# Is there a GetUserIdAsync() in Identity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asynchronous, asp.net-identity

Originally I had problems with the following error in an MVC Razor app (when clicking certain options twice before it had completed loading the page):

> A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

So I started working *with* async methods as MS suggest. This involved cascading async change throughout multiple controller actions (implementing `async` has been likened to a "Zombie Virus" in the way it spreads and I am inclined to agree).

I am still getting that error with the following async method in an injected CurrentCandidate class:

```
    public async Task<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUserAsync()
    {
        var applicationUser = await this._userManager.FindByIdAsync(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        return applicationUser;
    }
```

Presumably this is because `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()` is running something async *behind the scenes*.

I assumed, as it is an MS lib, there would be an async version of `GetUserId()`, but I cannot find one (or any documentation to say it exists)

What are my options here? I am under some pressure from a colleague to drop the `async` approach completely, but that will just lead back to the same error in another place.

Suggestions?

**Update:**

Separate the two calls into separate lines results in a clearer picture. The crash is on the `FindByIdAsync()`:

```
    public async Task<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUserAsync()
    {
        var id = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var applicationUser = await this._userManager.FindByIdAsync(id); <<<< crashes here
        return applicationUser;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using EF? You are only allowed one asynchronous operation per context. Make sure you have awaited your previous async call before calling FindByIdAsync!

Comment: Ooh and stick with async!

Comment: @heymega: All calls to `ApplicationUserAsync` are `await`ing it. The error occurs on this one line of code. Back to my actual question: Is there an async version of GetUserId()?

Comment: The error is with the FindByIdAsync method. You have a connection still open which you havent closed the exception doesn't lie. With regards to the GetUserId there is no async version. Why does this need to be async?

Comment: @heymega: You are correct (see update). `FindByIdAsync ` is the problem. What should I be looking for to identify the connection leak?

Comment: Check any entities you are querying and make sure the connections are closed. Make sure when youre querying your entities you're enumerating the Iqueryable object i.e. add ToList()

Comment: @heymega: The only database access running is via the UserManager. I am currently putting parallel non-async method in place to see what be going on.

Comment: @heymega: Sadly, when I move to non-async methods for all the related calls, the problem goes away. I suspect it is something to do with the injection of a static database instance. As this is now an X-Y question, I will close it as correctly answered (below) and post a new question when I have more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()` does not have async version. `GetUserId` is is not connected to EF or any async operations. Here is the source code: https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Extensions/IdentityExtensions.cs 
All it does is reaches into cookie data and gets claim value related to the UserId.

So you'll need to find other operation that causes your issue.

Comment: Yes the cause is in the call to `FindByIdAsync` (see update). Looking for ways to narrow down the cause now.

Comment: Try sync version of this method `FindById(user.Id)` and remove async/await from the method.

Comment: Moving to non-async appears to be a backward step for the project, but you have answered the original question. I will post a new question once I have more information. Thanks.